# Route all computers through one external IP

Tags: routing

Sorry in advance if the title is wrong.

I have a (kubernetes) cluster of computers and I would like to have one static IP that all machines share when making requests to external services like databases.

A real world example of this is Segment.io - they ask you to whitelist two ip addresses that all of their servers make requests through. This afford them the ability to spin up as many servers as they need but never ask their clients to whitelist more ip addresses.

My two questions are: what is this called and what technology does it use? I know that load balancing is for incoming traffic, so what this is called when it is regarding outgoing traffic?

The second question is how can I achieve this on a cloud platform like Google Cloud, AWS, or Azure.

Networking is not my strength so I apologize if I described any of this incorrectly.

Comment: Changing one or both of the addresses on packets is call NAT (Network Address Translation). When you hide multiple addresses behind a single address, the correct terminology is NAPT (Network Address Port Translation). The servers or cloud configurations are off-topic here. If you can give use the specific router or firewall model and configuration, we can help with the necessary changes to enable NAT.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a standard NAT solution that you would have at your home internet connection. The relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#One-to-many_NAT) page

At home you would use a router to translate your private IP (RFC 1918) addresses of your home PC/laptop to the public IP assigned by your provider. This can also be done with a private IP address, so translating from private to private.

Edit: to clear some things up: your home is not the only place to use NAT. A lot of companies use NAT to provide internet access, a lot of loadbalancers also use NAT.

Comment: This is between servers hosted on a cloud platform (GCP, Azure, AWS) and databases elsewhere on the internet. My home isn't part of this equation. I will research NATs though.

Comment: @bg__ on AWS for example you would use a NAT Gateway component to achieve this (or a NAT instance priori to late 2015). All VMs behind the NAT Gateway will be "hidden" behind the NAT Gateway's public IP.